# Group Certain Rows Together in T-SQL Based on Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
select MT.* 
from MyTable MT 
where 0 = 0  
order by ChangeDate, Type, ItemNumber
```

Which returns the following:

```
TableID    ChangeDate    Description    ItemNumber    Type
-------    ----------    -----------    ----------    ----
11259      2019-05-20    Item1          1335          MOVE
11260      2019-05-20    Item2          1475          MOVE
11261      2019-05-20    Item3          1782          UPDATE
11262      2019-05-20    Item4          1789          UPDATE
11263      2019-05-20    Item5          1782          MOVE
```

I'm trying to group together rows with the same ItemNumber (example: 1782) and am having difficulty trying to achieve this with a GROUP BY clause because I can't figure out how to manipulate an associated aggregate method to achieve that. Anyone?

**UPDATE**

To be more specific I would like rows with the same ItemNumber to be next to each other as follows:

```
TableID    ChangeDate    Description    ItemNumber    Type
-------    ----------    -----------    ----------    ----
11259      2019-05-20    Item1          1335          MOVE
11260      2019-05-20    Item2          1475          MOVE
11261      2019-05-20    Item3          1782          UPDATE
11263      2019-05-20    Item5          1782          MOVE
11262      2019-05-20    Item4          1789          UPDATE
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but you have not at all explained what results you want -- *how* you want to aggregate the data and what problems you are having.  Your question is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'll update it to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want a different `ORDER BY` clause - I don't see how this relates to aggregation (`GROUP BY`). It looks like it should be:

```
order by ChangeDate, ItemNumber, TableID
```

Or, possibly:

```
order by ItemNumber, ChangeDate, Type
```